# How to fill the canvas inside DIV

Tags: html, css, canvas, angular-material, chart.js

I have the following UI

[image: UI]

I am trying to fill the chart in the first DIV box. But it is overflowing

how to make the canvas to fill the height and width of div but not overflow

Here is the part of the code i am using

```
<div layout="row" style="Height:300px">
        <div flex="50" layout="column" flex-order="1" style="background-color:white" layout-margin md-whiteframe="1">

            <div>
                <h4 md-colors="{color: 'default-primary-hue-2'}" flex> Automated Tests</h4>
            </div>
            <div flex >
                <canvas id="myChart" style="max-height:inherit;overflow:hidden;"></canvas>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: As soon as parent is flex then the canvas itself shall be a flex to span available space.

Comment: set ur width and height of ur canvas